# How to prepend a path to a buildout-generated script

Tags: python, path, buildout

Scripts generated by `zc.buildout` using `zc.recipe.egg`, on our `<package>/bin/` directory look like this:

```
#! <python shebang> -S

import sys
sys.path[0:0] = [
    ... # some paths derived from the eggs
    ... # some other paths included with zc.recipe.egg `extra-path`
]

# some user initialization code from zc.recipe.egg `initialization`

# import function, call function
```

What I have not been able to was to find a way to *programmatically* **prepend** a path at the `sys.path` construction introduced in every script. Is this possible?

Why: I have a version of my python project installed globally and another version of it installed locally (off-buildout tree). I want to be able to switch between these two versions.

Note: Clearly, one can use the `zc.recipe.egg`/`initialization` property to add something like:

```
initialization = sys.path[0:0] = [ /add/path/to/my/eggs ]
```

But, is there any other way? Extra points for an example!

Comment: Why can't you disable the locally installed path so the globally installed version is picked up instead?

Comment: The scenario is like this: I develop some software which is installed with CMake. This software has python bindings to C++ code. The software may be installed locally on the machine I work on. I may need to checkout a new version of the software and test my external package against that new build, or vice-versa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I got a working environment by creating my own buildout recipe that you can find here: https://github.com/idiap/local.bob.recipe. The file that contains the recipe is this one: https://github.com/idiap/local.bob.recipe/blob/master/config.py. There are lots of checks which are specific to our software at the class constructor and some extra improvements as well, but don't get bothered with that. The "real meat (TM)" is on the `install()` method of that class. It goes like this more or less:

```
egg_link = os.path.join(self.buildout['buildout']['eggs-directory'], 'external-package.egg-link')
f = open(egg_link, 'wt')
f.write(self.options['install-directory'] + '\n')
f.close()
self.options.created(egg_link)
return self.options.created()
```

This will do the trick. My external (CMake-based) package now only has to create the right `.egg-info` file in parallel with the python package(s) it builds. Than, I can tie, using the above recipe, the usage of a specific package installation like this:

```
[buildout]
parts = external_package python
develop = .
eggs = my_project
       external_package
       recipe.as.above

[external_package]
recipe = recipe.as.above:config
install-directory = ../path/to/my/local/package/build

[python]
recipe = zc.recipe.egg
interpreter = python
eggs = ${buildout:eggs}
```

If you wish to switch installations, just change the `install-directory` property above. If you wish to use the default installation available system wide, just remove altogether the `recipe.as.above` constructions from your `buildout.cfg` file. Buildout will just find the global installation w/o requiring any extra configuration. Uninstallation will work properly as well. So, switching between builds will just work.

Here is a fully working buildout `.cfg` file that we use here: https://github.com/idiap/bob.project.example/blob/master/localbob.cfg

The question is: Is there an easier way to achieve the same w/o having this external recipe?

Answer (score 0):

Well, what you miss is probably the most useful buildout extension, [mr.developer](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/mr.developer).
Typically the package, let's say `foo.bar` will be in some repo, let's say git.

Your buildout will look like

```
[buildout]
extensions = mr.developer

[sources]
foo.bar = git git@github.com:foo/foo.bar.git
```

If you don't have your package in a repo, you can use `fs` instead of `git`, have a look at the documentation for details.

Activating the "local" version is done by

```
./bin/develop a foo.bar
```

Deactivating by

```
./bin/develop d foo.bar
```

There are quite a few other things you can do with `mr.developer`, do check it out!

Comment: Unfortunately, mr.developer requires the egg to be in pristine source format so it can install the package. In our case, the package is already installed somewhere (our package is pre-built with CMake which manages other dependencies as well). From mr.developer's homepage, there is no clear command or set of options that allow me to say: "use a pre-installed package here". That is, ultimately, what I'm looking for. Please notice that the `zc.recipe.eggs` does something similar, but does not allow me to prepend the package directory to the search path, only append.